# Different breadcrumb navigation style on some pages

Tags: master-page, asp.net, breadcrumb

I am working on a theme for SharePoint 2010. While working on the header area, I ran into a very annoying problem regarding the breadcrumb navigation: It looks good everywhere, except for sites that are stored under **/_layouts/** or **/Sites/** (it's called 'Seiten' in German). I made screenshots of the correct and the wrong styling of the breadcrumb navigation:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code I use to get the breadcrumb:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"> 

    <asp:SiteMapPath 
        SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
        id="ContentMap"
        runat="server"
        PathSeparator="&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;"
        RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="True"
        SkinID="2"
        EnableTheming="False"
        EnableViewState="False"
        ShowToolTips="False">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I really have no idea why this is happening.
Maybe there is a different way to display a breadcrumb navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadcrumbs in SharePoint are weird animals :) 
Have you already tried to "remove" the ContentPlaceHolder "**PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb**".
Actually, don't remove it - but place it in a hidden panel somewhere in your masterpage. So that only the SiteMapPath control is left behind.

My guess would be that another SiteMapPath control is injected from within those application pages,... in that placeholder.

Comment: Woah! I would have never thought of that. It doesn't  make sense. I don't even try to understand why I have to hide the ContentPlaceHolder. But it works! It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a situation, don't sure if must be added as a different question. I put that control on my masterpage visible but with the `PathSeparatorTemplate` equals to "»" (without quotes). It's working on my pages but not on admin page like `people.aspx`. I notice that pages have `PathSeparator` equals to empty string, causing the behavior of showing the path without separator at all. Any workaround without modifying the markup con every admin aspx page on "layouts" folder? (SP2013)